# Tonga-Hunga Ha'apai circural pressure wave and antipodes

Tags: waves

In recent eruption of Tonga-Hunga Ha'apai there was a widely spread animation showing a pressure wave originating in 20.5700° N, 175.3800° W.   The pressure would cumulate again in the antipodic point of earth which, if I am not mistaken is south Algeria.

Are there any data available on pressure measurements from that area?

Comment: Perhaps. Not a lot of cities there, may or may not be many weather stations. The Earth Science folk might know more...

Comment: This may be a better fit on [earthscience.se].

Comment: I would expect the pressure wave to dissipate before it reaches the other side of the earth. But apparently, it reached as far as The Netherlands, so who knows? (https://nltimes.nl/2022/01/16/tonga-volcanic-eruption-shockwave-reached-netherlands)

Comment: An observatory I know in Germany, at 12180 km spherical distance to the event, measured a 2 hPa pressure blip (at a base pressure of 1025 hPa) 15.5 h after the event (naive delay 12180km/330m/s = 10 h). There was no event recorded after this, so this must have been the first, direct pass of the wave. That's as close as I can bring you to Algeria.

Comment: As for dissipation of the pressure wave: I would expect some amplification around that area.  I am not expecting anything major, but if it was 2hpa in Germany, then 5 hPa in Algeria would be kind of cool.

Answer (score 1):

Tamanrasset, Algeria was the antipode, and the pressure wave was measured to have circled earth 3 times.

https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/04/14/upshot/tonga-pressure-wave.html